# How to use Chatter in Odoo?

Tags: odoo, odoo-9, odoo-10

I want to use `Chatter` for students model, so that, when value of some field is changed then it is logged under student form

To achieve this, I did the following things:
1. Added this div

```xml
<div class="oe_chatter">
    <field name="message_follower_ids" widget="mail_followers"/>
    <field name="message_ids" widget="mail_thread"/>
</div>
```

in the student form.

It added the chatter, but when i clicked on `New Message` button, it gave the following error.

[image]

This could be because i haven't inherited `mail.thread` in student model.

2. Then i inherited this class in student model.

[image]

Then it again gave an error as shown below

[image]

I search this topic, but couldn't found anything.

It would be appreciated if someone could help me out.

Comment: it seems that you added some field , but have not update your module.Update your module and check again.

Comment: Thank you, it worked and not giving any error and i am able to post a new message, but when i changed a field value, it is not logging anything.

Comment: Which field value you changed ? Please provide more detail

Comment: I changed email_id, phone_no and a custom field named 'x_school_id' and i want to track changes made to these fields.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to log changes of specific fields you need so set the `track_visibility` attribute on each field you want to track:

```py
class OpStudent(models.Model):
    _name = 'op.student'
    _inherits = {
        'res.partner': 'partner_id',
    }
    _inherit = [
        'mail.thread',
        'ir.needaction_mixin',
    ]

    foo = fields.Char(track_visibility='always')
```

You may read more about it in the [official documentation](http://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/mixins.html#logging-changes).

Answer (score 1):

You're using Chatter for keeping the track on student details.

So I'll suggest another module which is working absolutely fine and keeps the track on student or any other model you want as I have personally used it.

I used  [audit log](https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/10.0/auditlog/). It tracks all the CRUD operations. It will create `Audit`
the menu in setting tab from there you can set the model which you want to track.

For reference you can check this image also.

[image: Demo Of Audit Log Creation]

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, but with `res.company`, I solved it like this:

```py
class ResCompany(models.Model):

    _name = 'res.company'
    _inherit = ['res.company','mail.thread', 'mail.activity.mixin']

    date_end = fields.Date(string="Fin Date",tracking=True)
```

and in xml:

```xml
<xpath expr="//form/sheet" position="after">

    <div class="oe_chatter">
    <field name="message_follower_ids" widget="mail_followers"/>
    <field name="message_ids" widget="mail_thread" />
    </div>
</xpath>
```

I hope, that it serves you.